# Why is Windows 11 not recognizing any Blu-ray burners?

Tags: windows, blu-ray

It appears that Windows 11 has stopped recognizing my Blu-Ray Drive as a Burner. The symptoms are the 'Format' option has disappeared from the right mouse menu and the eject option does not work.

I have 2 external USB BD Writers; a Full-sized Pioneer BDR-X12UBK external device and a Verbatim Low Profile External device, that identifies as a Pioneer BDR-UD03 in the Hardware Tab.

I have 2 machines running Windows 11, one is a generic i5 on an ASUS B460 Motherboard, the other is a Microsoft Surface Book 3.

If I plug the devices into either machine, then they show up in Disk Management and File Explorer as optical drives. If I right click on the drive and select eject in Disk Mangement, the disk tray opens, and no errors are reported.

On the Surface if I right click on either drive in Explorer I get 'Eject' and 'Format' as menu options and if I click on eject the drive tray opens.

On the i5/ASUS if I right click on either drive in Explorer there is no 'format' option, and if I click on 'eject' Windows reports "An error occurred while ejecting the CD Drive" and the disk tray remains closed.

I am using the same power supply and cables to attach the Burners to both systems. I have done a full reset / reinstall (including download from the cloud) of Windows 11 on the i5/ASUS machine and the problem still occurs.  There is no third-party software installed at the point the problem occurs. However, if I go-ahead and install Nero on i5/ASUS Nero does not see any Burners attached to my system.

On the i5/ASUS where the problem occurs the devices shows up in Device manager is reported as "Working Properly". The device can be used to read discs without problem.

The fact that two drives exhibit the same behavior makes me think it's a software / configuration issue, rather than a hardware issue.

At this point I am out of ideas.